# ¿Porque hay una fuga de memoria en este metodo de c#?

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un programa que necesita comparar dos mapas de bits y para ello usa la función que está puesta un poco más alante en la pregunta. El problema es que he comprobado casi del todo que hay una fuga de memoria en ella y cuando la uso en un bucle la cantidad de RAM que usa el programa empieza a subir sin parar hasta que se cierra el programa. Esta es la función:

```
public static bool Comparar(Bitmap b1, Bitmap b2)
        {
            bool resultado;

            if ( (b1 == null) != (b2 == null))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (b1.Size != b2.Size)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var bd1 = b1.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), b1.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            var bd2 = b2.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), b2.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            try
            {
                IntPtr bd1scan0 = bd1.Scan0;
                IntPtr bd2scan0 = bd2.Scan0;

                int stride = bd1.Stride;
                int len = stride * b1.Height;

                resultado = (memcmp(bd1scan0, bd2scan0, len) == 0);
            }
            finally
            {
                b1.UnlockBits(bd1);
                b2.UnlockBits(bd2);
            }

            return resultado;
        }
```

Imagino que es de la función LockBits pero no entiendo porque ni como arreglarlo.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar esta comparación: `if ( (b1 == null) != (b2 == null)) `? No la comprendo.

Comment: Solo tenemos una parte del código que estás usando. ¿Podrías debugearlo y ver dónde se produce el problema?

Comment: @Mateo el código es un poco amplio y sería demasiado ponerlo. De todas maneras este metodo solo lo uso 1 vez en todo el código y si lo comento la fuga de memoria se arregla. Así he deducido que la fuga de memoria viene de ahí.

Comment: ¿Obtienes alguna excepción?  ¿Cuál? ¿Seguro que no puedes debugearlo y ver en qué instrucción se produce el problema?

Comment: Pero como tal que es lo que quieres hacer, ver si dos dibujos son iguales?

Comment: @Japv justo eso

Comment: @Mateo lo estoy intentando pero creo que el problema es que las imagenes que le paso a ese metodo no se borran nunca de la memoria. Casi seguro pero no conseigo poner nada en la pregunta que lo enseñe bien

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que por alguna razón no se estaban eliminando de la memoria los Bitmaps y cada vez que se usaba el metodo iba aumentando el consumo de RAM del programa. Añadiendo `b1.Dispose()` y `b2.Dispose()` se ha arreglado el problema.

Comment: Esta respuesta, aunque seguro es la correcta, es confusa, porque no pusiste en tu pregunta ni como obtenias los bitmaps, ni que hacias con ellos despues.. esto, dentro de tu metodo, no es correcto, porque seguro vienen de otro lado.. esto deberia estar donde los abrias y cerrabas no???... por favor, explica mejor la pregunta, el problema, y la solucion....

Answer (score 0):

Para saber si dos dibujos son iguales te propongo el siguiente código:

```
public static bool Comparar(Bitmap b1, Bitmap b2)
{
   bool sonIguales = true;

   if (b1.Height == b2.Height && b1.Width == b2.Width)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < b1.Width; i++)
      {
         if (sonIguales == false)
         {
            break;
         }

         for (int j = 0; j < b1.Height; j++)
         {
            var pixel1 = b1.GetPixel(i, j);
            var pixel2 = b2.GetPixel(i, j);

            if (pixel1 != pixel2)
            {
               sonIguales = false;
               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   else
   {
      sonIguales = false;
   }

   return sonIguales;
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es recorrer pixel por pixel cada **Bitmap**, comparándolos entre si, y en caso de que se detecte algún pixel diferente entre las dos imágenes pues ya no son iguales.

Comment: Posiblemente esté usando `LockBits` porque es más eficiente hacerlo así que con la función `GetPixel`. Aunque, si la velocidad no importa es mejor hacerlo de esta manera. https://mfranc.com/programming/operacje-na-bitmapkach-net-1/